# События скроллинга страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть задача сделать используя скроллинг страницы, осуществить подгрузку динамических данных при продвижении пользователя в конец страницы. В этом простом примере сделал событие на скроллинг и клик ссылки. И все это не работает почему-то... Подскажите, что не так? Ссылка тут: http://jsfiddle.net/948jU/

Comment: что такое scrollPagination? В jqapi нет такого

Comment: просто событие на скролл вешается так: http://jsfiddle.net/dG9YM/

Comment: Это я отсюда взял: http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/ Вообщем демо-пример работает, а как начинаю переделывать под себя, не пашет...

Comment: в fiddle - не работает. Надо подключить js из той статьи. Следующий синтаксис не валидный: { alert('ky-ky'); }

Comment: Я пробовал и на локальном сервере делать. Однако событие $('#jscroll').scrollPagination не отвечает никак, чтобы я там не писал. Хотя div jscroll есть такой... А демо пример работает, если только в файле ajax.php меняешь данные подключения бд. И в js файле там нет ничего особенного. Достаточно JQuery 1.8.3 подключить, чтобы событие scrollPagination работало по идее...

Comment: scrollPagination - это расширение для jq. В самом jq нету scrollPagination. Необходимо подключить jquery, и затем еще js'ку с этой либой "scrollPagination". И { alert('ky-ky'); } - код не валидный, то есть он выдает ошибку синтаксиса и никак не сработает. Смотрите в консоль

Answer (score 1):

Поделюсь опытом реализации сего велосипеда:

Использую perfectScrollbar, но по сути он меняет только внешний вид

В верстке:

```
<div class="result-box-container">
    <ul class="search-result-box">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

В скрипте:

```
var $resultBoxContainer = $('.result-box-container');
$resultBoxContainer.perfectScrollbar('update');
$resultBoxContainer.scroll(function() {
                var containerHeight = $('.result-box-container').height();
                var $searchResultBox = $('.search-result-box');
                var bottomPosition = $searchResultBox.position().top + $searchResultBox.height();
                if ((bottomPosition - containerHeight) < 450) {
                    loadMore();
                }
            });
```

Comment: loadMore - это что самописная функция тоже какая-то? И PerfectScrollbar - это в JQuery такой метод или все самописное?

Comment: loadMore - да, самописная функция. PerfectScrollbar - http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/

Comment: loadMore подгружает и вставляет элементы li в список (на самом деле вставляет knockoutjs). На loadMore стоит throttle.